# Wordpress not writing into debug.log even if WP_DEBUG=true

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm developing a simple plugin and I would need to see the logs by using error_log() function in my code.

I've added the DEBUG MODE into my wp-config.php file like this:

```
    // Enable WP_DEBUG mode
define('WP_DEBUG', true);

// Enable Debug logging to the /wp-content/debug.log file
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);

// Disable display of errors and warnings 
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
@ini_set('display_errors',0);

// Use dev versions of core JS and CSS files (only needed if you are 
modifying these core files)
define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
```

I'm using this wp_config.php content into two different WP instances (pre production and production) and unfortunately it only works into the pre production server...I don't know why it is not visible into my production server which is exactly the same...

I also checked for file permission and there are also the same...

any idea why I'm not able to see my plugin logs in the second server ?

Comment: try resetting the file permissions, which OS are you using?

Comment: it's a linux server don't know which release as this is a shared VM and I only have FTP access

Comment: I forgot to mention that only WordFence plugin is writing into it but not my plugin...

Comment: if wordfence is able to write but not yours then I am pretty sure that it's a permission issue. Can you access ssh ?

Comment: try this, create a log file mydebug.log and put this in your plugin,  error_log("This message is from my plugin ", 3 , "..../mydebug.log"); if this file contains message then plugin is able to write the debug logs .